# Unable to configure queryTimeout and connection keepAlive for Quarkus reactive datasource

Tags: quarkus, vert.x, oracleclient, quarkus-reactive

I am trying to set few properties like ***queryTimeout*** and ***keepAlive*** for my Quarkus reactive Oracle client but I am not able to find these properties in the Quarkus documentation.
How do we handle queryTimeout and connection keepAlive for Quarkus reactive datasources?

Comment: You may be able to do this in the connect string or (If you use Oracle Client libraries e.g. Instant Client) in  sqlnet.ora file. This is probably OK for the keep alive (aka EXPIRE_TIME). See [Oracle Database 21c Easy Connect Plus](https://download.oracle.com/ocomdocs/global/Oracle-Net-21c-Easy-Connect-Plus.pdf) which has details and links. But the query timeout (look for RECV_TIMEOUT in the [sqlnet.ora doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netrf/parameters-for-the-sqlnet.ora.html#GUID-4A19D81A-75F0-448E-B271-24E5187B5909)) will affect every statement execute.

Comment: Can you explain which properties you are referring to? Are these from JDBC? I couldn't find them in Oracle doc.